# How does the color of the atmosphere differ on Mars? Does the sky during sunset on Mars look just like midday?

Tags: mars, atmosphere

Higher frequency light wavelengths (blue) absorb more in our atmosphere. At sunset, light must travel farther to reach the observer, so more blue light is scattered and the sun/sky appears orange and red.

Since the atmosphere on Mars is so much less dense than Earth's, presumably less light would be scattered and absorbed in Mars' atmosphere. As a result, would the sky at sunset look just like midday? Furthermore, does Mars' sky even look blue from the ground, or is the atmosphere composition different enough that it produces a different color?

Comment: Possibly of interest to you: [Why would Mars' sky appear blue at dawn and dusk, but red during the middle of the day (reverse of Earth)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24108/12102) as well as [Terrestrial Exoplanet Skies – I've Built a Visual Sky Chart. Is it Accurate?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/24048/7982) and also [Color-correcting photos on Mars so that things look like they would on Earth - is it a big correction?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24746/12102)

Comment: See this answer: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/38931/is-dust-the-only-reason-why-the-martian-sky-is-so-bright/39150#39150